# Cannot connect to site after setting up load balancer and HTTPS?

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, ssl, spring-boot

I have a site set up on AWS using Spring Boot on port 5000. I was able to connect to the site fine using HTTP only. I want to set up HTTPS using Amazon's Certificate Manager to deploy an SSL certificate on a load balancer.

Here's my load balancer port setup:
[image: Port setup]

But now when I attempt to go to my site using HTTP or HTTPS, the request times out. (`ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`).

Why is the request timing out when it should be forwarding the requests to port 5000 (the port the site is hosted on)? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

check port 443 is open in the security group which your LB belongs.

Comment: It is open. 443, 80, and 5000 are open.

Comment: i hope you have cloudwatch enabled, its worth checking the logs.